# Best Javascript design pattern to use when the object requires DOM to be loaded first?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns, dom, asynchronous

I'm doing some stuff with the Google APIs and I want to structure my code to make it reusable but I'm running into difficulties. To authenticate using oauth2 I'm loading this script

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/auth.js?onload=initAuth"></script>
```

which called initAuth() when it was loaded. I could then do authentication using gapi.auth. However, because I am calling different APIs I want to create a more general wrapper class for the authentication. I had a look around the web and gave self executing anonymous functions a go as they look quite clean:

```
(function(GAuth, $, undefined) {

    GAuth.token = gapi.auth.getToken();

    GAuth.authenticate = function(clientId, scopes, apiUrl, isInitialAuth, callback) {
        if(isInitialAuth)
        {
            gapi.auth.init(function() {
                authorize(clientId, scopes, apiUrl, false, callback);
            });
        }

        else
        {
            // authorize is private
            authorize(clientId, scopes, apiUrl, true, callback);
        }
    }

    ...etc...

}(window.GAuth = window.GAuth || {}, jQuery));
```

The problem with this is it executes immediately, and in this instance I get a "gapi is undefined" error. I'm looking for a way that allows me to load my GAuth object after the other scripts have loaded, and one that preferably allows me to define public and private functions/variables.

Comment: Include the file that sets up `gapi` before you require this this file.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/). It may be a hassle at first, but will solve dependency problems and "load-first" issues in the long run.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer RequireJS is overkill for smaller projects and it's even more of pain when you get into merging and uglifying the code. I'm not talking it down - for large modular projects it can be a viable option much like CommonJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the file that sets up `gapi` before you require this this file. This will ensure `gapi` has a value by the time this script executes. Since you're using jQuery you can also use the document ready (very recommended for code that is dependent upon the page being ready first).

```
// Define functions here
$(function() {
    // Do your code dependent on a completely loaded DOM here
});
```